# What do Java synchronized(Object obj) really block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose we have the following class

```
class Class1 {

    public void Method1() {
        synchronized(myobject) {
            /* some code */
        }
    }
}
```

where myobject is the instance of the class

```
class myClass {

     public void Method2() {
        synchronized(someOtherObj) {
            /* some code */
        }
     }

     public synchronized void Method3() {
        /* some code without synchronized blocks */
     }

     public void Method4() {
        /* some code without synchronized blocks */
     }
}
```

Help me please to understand which code blocks of myobject are made available only for the tread called the method Method1.

Comment: can you please rephrase.

Comment: It is impossible. But you can block access to your own class by adding special check to all methods of your class.

Comment: What do you mean by *prevent using of myObject in other threads at all*?

Comment: I've rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to synchronize something.  You can make a method synchronized:

```
public synchronized void doSomething() { 
    // safe to do stuff
}
```

or you can synchronize on an object:

```
synchronize( object ) {
    // safe to do stuff
}
```

In your example, Class1.Method1 and myClass.Method3 and myClass.Method4 will all block each other.  myClass.Method2 is locking someOtherObject which doesn't affect anything in the example.

What can be confussing is when you add the synchronized keyword to a method, it is really just locking the 'this' reference.

```
public synchronized void method() { }
```

is the same as:

```
public void method() {
    synchronized( this ) {
         // this may help clarify
    }
}
```

That is all you get.  When the object are synchronized, they cannot be accessed by any other objects in any other threads.  This stuff can be difficult to get right.  I recommend the following book:

Java Concurrency in Practice 
by Brian Goetz et al. 
Link: http://amzn.com/0321349601

Answer (score 0):

**Help me please to understand which code blocks of myobject are made available only for the tread called the method Method1.**

I think you have synchronization backwards.  No other thread can execute the block inside of `Class1#Method1()` unless it is holding the `myobject` "lock". The actual methods of `myClass` are unaffected.  Any methods from any threads can invoke methods of `myobject` if they have a reference to it. (Since the methods in `myClass` are also synchronized, they may also block but that is a separate issue.)

For that reason, it is important to always make the object you are locking on private and not publish the reference by returning it in any public method.

Comment: You're right, I have a lack of understanding of synchronization. But I try to master it.

Comment: Why then do we need put any object as "lock"? What will change if I use some other object, for example synchronized(this).

Comment: `synchronized(this)` is the same as putting the synchronize keyword in the method declaration.  The point of any lock is to only allow one thread inside the block that is being held by the lock.  You can also lock on the same object in different methods.  For example, in some kind of `Collection`  object, you want to both lock the `get()` and the `remove()` and `size()` methods with the same lock so anyone trying to get an object or get the size will get the correct answer even if another thread is removing something at the "same time".

Comment: Like @Timothy-Wright, I too recommend you read Java Concurrency In Practice

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that

```
void synchronized myfunc()
```

is short-hand for:

```
void myfunc() {
  synchronized (this) {
  }
}
```

where `this` is the current instance of the class called from outside.

So if you have the following setup:

```
final MyClass a = new MyClass();

// Thread 1:
a.myfunc();

// Thread 2:
a.myfunc();
```

Then both threads will wait on the **same** object (which is the instance a).

However in the following setup:

```
final MyClass a = new MyClass();
final MyClass b = new MyClass();

// Thread 1:
a.myfunc();

// Thread 2:
b.myfunc();
```

Both threads can access `myfunc` at the same time, because they synchronize on different objects (instance a for thread 1 and instance b for thread 2).

If you would write the code in the following way:

```
final Object a = new Object();
final Object b = new Object();

static void myfunc() {}

// Thread 1:
synchronized(a) {
  myfunc();
}

// Thread 2:
synchronized(b) {
  myfunc();
}
```

It would be the exact same thing (considering blocking), because - as above - a synchronized method is just a short-hand expression for `synchronized(this)`.